# Once Doraemon stated that old things get valuable in the future. Couldn't anyone time travel to steal things from the past and sell them in the future

Tags: doraemon

In the future, couldn't anyone just travel through time to steal valuable things from the past, like dinosaur bones to sell them in the future? Then why is time travel allowed?

Now if you say about Time Patrol who prevent wrong use of time travel, wouldn't it mean they always keep a watch on everyone in any time period, thus violating privacy rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you guessed the plot of [Doraemon: Nobita's Dinosaur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doraemon:_Nobita%27s_Dinosaur) and its 2006 remake.

Criminals that abuse Time Travel do indeed exist and there is a special Time Police that works to prevent abuse. That same sentiment is shown in multiple other episodes where some form of "Time Police" appears (for example when they show a park with robot replicas of endangered animals).

Why not prevent Time travel? Well... ask yourself. Now that the technology is know, do you think any force in the world would be able to stop anyone from making an atom bomb? Especially when they are already criminal outlaws in the first place? Best you can do is minimize damage.

That said, it is not like Doraemon's gadgets aren't know for being weapons of mass destruction disguised as toys.

You had things like

- pills or other items that give Superman like powers
- items that can create multidimensional spaces
- tons of brainwashing devices that can go from putting you in an egg shaped machine so that you will fall in love with the first person you see or go out at night in your underwear because someone summoned you to a cherry blossom party and not remember anything afterward
- multiple ways to impersonate other persons
- city destruction level weapons, including anime style super robots
- buttons that can erase people from reality, including other's memories of them ever existing
- devices that can be used to **summon the DEVIL**

It is scary to think some of those even exist in the first place. I wouldn't try to rationalize what they do in the show.

Otherwise poor Shizuka should already have moved to a different country after all the damage Nobita and Doraemon caused her (from the repeated bath joke to thinks like brainwashing her on multiple occasions, selling her dolls without asking first, writing on her diary, impersonating her, etc etc etc)